# Android switching between layout(Forms)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am fairly new to the android development platform.

I am developing a small android help desk application, as a project. My problem is switching between my layouts. now there are a lot of help on the internet but could not find anything use full to my application.

I have a "main.xml" layout file and a "login.xml" layout file. I can not find a proper way to switch between the two layouts.

I though setting the context view to the other layout will work. but i keep on getting a force close message on my simulator

```
      setContentView(R.layout.login);
```

So as you can see i have an login screen and as soon as the user logged in the layout needs to change to the main layout.

Comment: on what basis  you want to switch between the layouts?

Comment: PLease be specific with your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, you can not change the content view of the activity.

However, you can create a new activity for example `LoginActivity` and set its content view with
`setContentView(R.layout.login);` and then you can switch to this layout by creating an intent which will open the new activity as below.

`startActivity(new Intent (YourActivity.this, TheActivitytobeopened.class));`

Answer (score 0):

I have an activity with a LinearLayout. And then I dynamically add and remove views to it.

```
LinearLayout llMain = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.room_layout_main);
roomView = new RoomView(this);
llMain.addView(roomView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
//use llMain.removeView(roomView) to remove it
```

I am pretty sure you can load views from xml but I am not sure. Hope that helps. 
EDIT- looks like you can load a view from xml, see here: http://www.aslingandastone.com/2011/dynamically-changing-android-views-with-xml-layouts/